# Cannot get a process builder to fire

Tags: process-builder, approval-process, process

I have created a process builder, that is supposed to fire when a record is submitted for approval in one object. It is using the criteria of "when file is created or changed" and using a field changing when the record is submitted for approval as a condition.

The process builder has the action set to create a record in another object, but is not firing at all.

Is there anyway to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: silly question, did you activate the process? Can you paste the screenshot of the process builder with the criterias

Comment: Yes the process is activated, I can go grab a screenshot

Comment: can you also paste the action?

Comment: added it! hope that helps

Comment: Because the intial criteria is a picklist, do you mind trying by adding 2 conditions 1) Fieldname ISCHANGHED equals true / ADD ROW / 2) Fieldname equals Active? I am looking at documentation to see the order of execution on where Approvals and processbuilder falls

Comment: is this Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change Checked in your field update in the approval process?

Comment: Also make sure the Recursion - Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction? is set unchecked in the process builder at Choose object and specify when to start the process (ie) Step 1  in the PB. Because you enabled the Re-evaluvate flag on the field update for every time the recursion occurs a new record will get inserted if not. You may end up seeing 6 records for the child object( I ended up checking the flag  and saw this behavior)

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure ***Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change*** is Checked in your field update setting the picklist value in your approval process, for the process builder to be triggered.
2. Also make sure the ***Recursion - Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction?***
   is unchecked in the process builder at ***Choose object and specify when to start the process*** (ie) Step 1 in the PB.

Because you enabled the Re-evaluvate flag on the field update for every time the recursion occurs a new record will get inserted if not. You may end up seeing 6 records for the child object( I ended up checking the flag and saw this behavior)